# How to use Django ORM for multiple inner joins on nested foreign keys

Tags: python, django, orm, prefetch

I would like to do multiple joins on some django models with a filter on one of the joined tables.

Here is what the raw SQL would look like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.description FROM public.customer_customerhiernode AS c 
    INNER JOIN public.territory_management_territorycustomer AS tc ON tc.customer_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN public.territory_management_territorynode AS tn ON tn.id = tc.territory_node_id
    INNER JOIN public.territory_management_territoryuser AS tu ON tu.territory_node_id = tn.id
    INNER JOIN public.authentication_user AS u ON u.id = tu.user_id
    WHERE u.username = %s
```

This is what I've tried so far, it is filtering correctly at territorycustomers, but when I fetch the CustomerHierNode, it gets all of them.

```
users = TerritoryUser.objects.select_related('user').filter(user__username=username)
territorycustomers = TerritoryCustomer.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('territory_node__territoryuser_set', queryset=users))
customers = CustomerHierNode.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('territorycustomer_set', queryset=territorycustomers))
```

I want to join these tables and get all their fields as a flat dictionary. Is this possible with the ORM? I also want this to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: Please show your models and a sample of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I want to get the prefetched foreign keys for the joins, either nested in the ORM or in a flat dict with all the properties from all the joined tables.